# High availability with corosync and load balancing with DNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, corosync

I have a HA cluster with 2 nodes.

This cluster will use floating IP address let's say: 10.10.10.100

The question is will it be possible to use DNS loadbalancing in such case for this cluster?

For example: host.com is domain name for my 2 nodes.

host.com will be an alias for host-ha.com for which A record is floating IP address: 10.10.10.100. And host-ha.com will be an alias for host.dns.com for which 2 A records exist 10.10.10.101 and 10.10.10.102.

Will loadbalancing work in such way?

I know this is an ugly way but it is interesting for me to try it out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, if 10.10.10.100 and 10.10.10.101 points to HA IP:s then your setup makes sense to me.

You don't want to mix floating IP:s with non-floating ones in your DNS setup however, since then you defeat the purpose of having a HA setup in the first place.

What would make sense is having something like

```
host-ha.com. A   10.10.10.100 # Floating IP
host-ha.com. A   10.10.10.101 # Floating IP
host-ha.com. A   10.10.10.102 # Floating IP
```

Since you can have multiple configured floating IP addresses.

Comment: Great thank you for your opinion. It really makes sense!!!